# Problems with steam in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, steam

I have Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit installed. I also have steam installed. Steam launches normally each time but every time I search Team Fortress 2 it loads for a short time and then closes automatically. I went "Google is my friend". I couldn't find any answers that are related to my problem. Here's the log:

```
    Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
    STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
    removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 4027 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_96DA982A39FA7DF8543B1689BF458644
    removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 4027 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_96DA982A39FA7DF8543B1689BF458644
    removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 4027 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
    removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 4027 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
    Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    [0610/132850:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)

    (steam:4221): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_simple_async_result_complete() called from wrong context!
    Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
    Generating new string page texture 3: 384x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    `menu_proxy_module_load': /home/desertedfreeman/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

    (steam:4221): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)


    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4221): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    Adding license for package 0
    Adding license for package 13674
    Adding license for package 28208
    Adding license for package 28221
    Adding license for package 28305
    Adding license for package 28367
    Adding license for package 28368
    roaming config store loaded successfully - 1416 bytes.
    migrating temporary roaming config store
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1370553818_client)
    ExecCommandLine: "/home/desertedfreeman/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam"
    Generating new string page texture 74: 256x256, total string texture memory is 704.51 KB
    Generating new string page texture 75: 128x256, total string texture memory is 835.58 KB
    Generating new string page texture 76: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
    Generating new string page texture 77: 32x256, total string texture memory is 868.35 KB
    Generating new string page texture 78: 64x256, total string texture memory is 933.89 KB
    CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
    System startup time: 10.76 seconds
    Running Steam on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit
    STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/desertedfreeman/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
    ExecCommandLine: "/home/desertedfreeman/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
    ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
    [0610/132914:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
    [0610/132915:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
    [0610/132915:ERROR:reference_audio_renderer.cc(45)] Not implemented reached in virtual void media::ReferenceAudioRenderer::OnCreated(media::AudioOutputController*)
    [0610/132915:ERROR:reference_audio_renderer.cc(49)] Not implemented reached in virtual void media::ReferenceAudioRenderer::OnPlaying(media::AudioOutputController*)
    [0610/132915:ERROR:alsa_output.cc(684)] Failed querying delay: Input/output error
    Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
    /tmp/dumps/crash_20130610132915_1.dmp
    /home/desertedfreeman/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 704:  4221 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
    Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
    response: CrashID=bp-4f2229f2-1527-42c8-89b4-0b9e52130610
```

Please help.

Comment: Seems like Alsa problem. Do you have any problem with other programs with audio?

Comment: It's related with sound because you can read this errors before the crash dump: [0610/132915:ERROR:alsa_output.cc(684)] Failed querying delay: Input/output error

Comment: Sorry I messed up on that comment so I'm making a new one to clear this up. Google Chrome, Firefox ,Rythmbox...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem, but instead of it happening whenever I'm searching for games, it happened when I tried to view an individual game's store page. The video would load, then crash the entire application. The problem here is that Steam doesn't include Adobe Flash in its libs (or Plugins folder, whatever is their intent). Therefore, whenever Steam tries to load something that needs Flash, it borks completely.

Here's a link to the solution on Steam Support: [Using Flash on 64-bit Distributions](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1493-GHZB-7612).

For future reference, you want to be as detailed as possible whenever asking for help on AskUbuntu. It would help tremendously to know whenever if you're on a 32-bit or a 64-bit install, and whenever if you're using AMD/nvidia drivers. I tried asking a question a couple days ago; got no answer, because the question I asked was too broad in scope, and I also didn't give enough details. Hope this helps!